# Clear input field value after javascript alert

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, getelementsbyname

I have a dynamic field that get value from database, and I want to check one of the field value if it was greater from the old value or not. If it does greater, i have to give an alert and reset field value back to `''`

i want to do it without using `document.GetElementById` because the field was looped by foreach, I'm tryin to work with `document.GetElementByName` but got no where. here's my code

```
<?php foreach ($items->result_array() as $row){ ?>
    <tr>
        <td><p><?php echo $row['nmbr']; ?> </p>
            <p><?php echo $row['urai']; ?><p> </td>
        <td><?php echo $row['jml']?> </td>
        <td><div class="oldprice"><?php echo $row['oldprice']?></div></td>
        <td><input id="pnwrn" class="pnwrn" type="text" name="pnwrn[]"  value="" data-harga="<?php echo $row['jml']?>" data-jumlah="<?php echo $row['oldprice']?>"/></td>
        <td><div class="output"></div></td>
    </tr>

<?php } ?>
```

and this is my javascript :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $('.pnwrn').on('change', function () {
        var twrn = $(this).val();
        var price = parseInt($(this).data('harga'));
        var jmlh = parseInt($(this).data('jumlah'));
        if (twrn <= jmlh){
            $(this).parents('tr').find('.output').html(twrn*price);
        }
        else {
            alert("Price can not be greater from old price");
            cleartext();
        }

    });

    function clearInputs() {
        document.getElementByName("pnwrn").value = "";
    }
</script>
```

can someone help me?

Comment: is jQuery ok to use?

Comment: @TheOneandOnlyChemistryBlob: He's already using jQuery (`$(this).parents('tr')...`)

Comment: I just saw that...he didn't have jQuery as a tag

Comment: soryy, my bad, i forget the tag :)

Answer (score 0):

You are not supposed to have multiple elements with the same `id`. Instead, try this:

```
<td><input id="pnwrn<?php echo $row['some_id_field_that_you_have']; ?>" class="pnwrn" type="text" name="pnwrn[<?php echo $row['some_id_field_that_you_have']; ?>]"  value="" data-harga="<?php echo $row['jml']?>" data-jumlah="<?php echo $row['oldprice']?>"/></td>
```

You can also attach the matching ID on the `<tr>`, or to other elements, which makes it trivial to find the appropriate elements.

Unfortunately, with names like `urai`, `harga`, `jumlah` and `pnwrn`, it is extremely hard to pinpoint what exactly you're trying to do, thus just vague hints.

But - if you're trying to clear the very field you're checking, you already have it, so no lookup needs to be done. Just do `clearInput(this)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to loop through all the inputs and match on the class you want:

```
$("input").each(function (i) {
    if ($(this).prop("class") === "pnwrn") {
        $(this).val('');
    }
});
```